# variables for background-image urls..... in jupyterlab4 themes

Tags: jupyter-lab

I'm creating a theme for a Jupyterlab 4 notebook-server, and I want to replace the original jupyter logo with one of my own.

Ultimately, I want to be able to change the logo based on some external input (css's `env` id probably the way I'll go for that)

I believe the basic concept is right:

```
:root {
  --nb-type-url: 'https://example.com/images/my_logo.png';  
}

<snip />

#jp-MainLogo {
  background-image: url(--nb-type-url);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

<snip />
```

If I try this in a jupyterlab4 theme, I get an error:

```
...
      '35 | #jp-MainLogo {\n' +
      '36 |   background-image: url(${___CSS_LOADER_URL_REPLACEMENT_0___});\n' +
      '37 |   background-size: contain;\n' +
      '38 |   background-repeat: no-repeat;\n' +
      '39 | }\n' +
...
      '52 | // Exports\n' +
      '53 | /* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = (___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___);\n' +
      '54 | \n' +
      '    at processResult (/some/path/jupyterlab-template/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:841:19)\n' +
      '    at /some/path/jupyterlab-template/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:964:5\n' +
      '    at /some/path/jupyterlab-template/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:400:11\n' +
      '    at /some/path/jupyterlab-template/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:195:20\n' +
      '    at context.callback (/some/path/jupyterlab-template/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)\n' +
      '    at /some/path/jupyterlab-template/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js:250:9\n' +
      '    at /some/path/jupyterlab-template/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/LoaderPlugin.js:209:27\n' +
      '    at /some/path/jupyterlab-template/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:5113:17\n' +
      '    at symbolIterator (/some/path/jupyterlab-template/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3485:9)\n' +
      '    at timesSync (/some/path/jupyterlab-template/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2297:7)',
    compilerPath: undefined
```

(if I hard-code the url, it works just fine)

Am I actually doing the variable placement incorrectly, or is this currently not something the system can cope with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went for a cheating solution: I load a named graphic from a location relative to the css:

```
  background-image: url('images/my_graphic.png');
```

... and then physically replace the graphic for each variation.

I admit this only really works when the jupyter instance is being created in a docker image

Answer (score 0):

This looks like webpack being too eager with substitution. You could try defining the URL value in the variable like:

```css
:root {
  --nb-type-url: url('https://example.com/images/my_logo.png');  
}


#jp-MainLogo {
  background-image: var(--nb-type-url);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If not, you can override webpack config in extensions (https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_dev.html#webpackconfig), either overriding the CSS loader for a dumber one, or configuring the assets path properly but these are complicated and brittle solutions for what seems to be a mistake in defining the url variable.